# Adding "data-hover" to Wordpress Menu Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out a way to add "data-hover" to my menu items on Wordpress, i.e:

I want to place:

```
data-hover="ABOUT US"
```

into

```
<a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
```

without being able to manually change the link html itself so that it becomes:

```
<a href="#" data-hover="ABOUT US">ABOUT US</a>
```

But Wordpress is insanely tedious to use and I can't find a way to achieve this without javascript. So could someone give me some ideas on how to do this?

Comment: I think js is the ticket because you don't want to edit WP core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your functions.php in theme

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_custom_data_atts_to_nav', 10, 4 );
function add_custom_data_atts_to_nav( $atts, $item, $args ) {

$atts['data-hover'] = $item->title;
return $atts;}
```

hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-hover', $(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
<a href="#">FOO BAR</a>
```

But i highly recommend to edit actual view instead of that dirty solution.

Comment: You weren't kidding haha. It completely breaks my slider and a few other things. Any other ideas?

Comment: this will add data-hover to each and every anchor in the document. and can conflict to other JS functions as well...what has happened with @Leurus

Comment: @thakur.B yep, that is why i recommend to not use it, Leurus didn't provide more details like wrapper container of wanted scope so it works globally for etire document.